# Determine the distribution and the expected value of $Z_1=XY_1$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X, Y_1, Y_2$ be independent random variables, all are defined on the same probability space.

Let $X$ be Bernoulli distributed on $\{0,1\}$ with sucessparameter $p_0\in (0,1)$ and let $Y_i,\ i=1,2$ be binomial distributed with parameter $(n,p), \ n\in \mathbb{N}, p\in (0,1)$.

(a) Determine the distribution and the expected value of $Z_1=XY_1$.

(b) Determine the covariance of $Z_1=XY_1$ and $Z_2=XY_2$.

$$$$

For question (a) :

We have that $$P(X=0)=1-p_0 \ \text{ and} \ P(X=1)=p_0$$ and $$P(Y_1=y)=\binom{n}{y}p_0^y(1-p_0)^{n-y}$$

For $Z$ do we calculate the product of these two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without doing a lot of calculation, just observe that $Z_1=XY_1$ can take the values in

$$\{0;1;2;\dots;n\}$$

$Z_1$ will take the value zero when $X=0$, that is with probability $1-p_0$ plus when $X=1$ and $Y_1=0$, thus with probability $p_0(1-p)^n$

Concluding:

$$P(Z_1=0)=1-p_0+p_0(1-p)^n$$

For the rest of support values, the probabilities are the binomial ones multiplied by $p_0=P(X=1)$

As per the expectation is concerned, the text says that the rv are independent thus...

(same reasoning for $Z_2$)

For the covariance, simply expand the definition formula and easy get the solution:

$$Cov(Z_1,Z_2)=\mathbb{V}[X]\cdot\mathbb{E}^2[Y_1]=p_0(1-p_0)\cdot n^2p^2$$

Comment: The expected value of $Z_1$ is then the product of the expected value of $X$ and the expected value of $Y_1$, right?

Comment: @MaryStar absolutely right!

Comment: So do we get \begin{equation*}E[Z_1]=E[XY_1] =E[X]\cdot E[Y_1]=p_0\cdot np=np_0p\end{equation*} ?

Comment: As for the covariance : $$\text{Cov}(Z_1, Z_2)=E[Z_1Z_2]-E[Z_1]E[Z_2]=E[XY_1Y_2]-E[Z_1]E[Z_2]$$ How do we get the formula you have?

Comment: @Mary Star: first $Z_1Z_2 \neq XY_1Y_2$. Second $E(Z_1)=E(Z_2)$. Third why don't you mark my answer as accepted first?

Comment: Does it hold that $E(Z_1)=E(Z_2)$ bevause $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ have the same properties? So we have that \begin{equation*}E[Z_1]=E[XY_1] =E[X]\cdot E[Y_1]=p_0\cdot np=np_0p\end{equation*} and teh samealsofor $Z_2$, right? As for the covariance we have then that $\text{Cov}(Z_1, Z_2)=E[Z_1Z_2]-E[Z_1]E[Z_2]=E[Z_1Z_2]-E[Z_1]^2$, right? How do we continue?

Comment: I don't really see how we get $\mathbb{V}[X]\cdot\mathbb{E}^2[Y_1]$,could you give me a hint?

Comment: @MaryStar :$$Cov(Z_1,Z_2)=\mathbb{E}[XY_1XY_2]-\mathbb{E}[XY_1]\mathbb{E}[XY_2]=$$

$$=\mathbb{E}[X^2]\mathbb{E}[Y_1]\mathbb{E}[Y_2]-[\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y_1]]^2=$$

$$=\{\mathbb{E}[X^2]-\mathbb{E}^2[X]\}\mathbb{E}^2[Y_1]=\mathbb{V}[X]\mathbb{E}^2[Y_1]$$

Comment: Ahh I see!! So it is equal to $\left [p_0(1-p_0)\right ]\cdot \left (np\right )^2$, right?

Answer (score 1):

You have :

$$P(Z_1=k)=P(Z_1=k|X=0)P(X=0)+P(Z_1=k|X=1)P(X=1) \\
= P(X=0)\delta_{k,0}+P(Y_1=k|X=1)P(X=1)\\
=(1-p_0)\delta_{k,0}+\binom{n}{k}p_0^{k+1}(1-p_0)^{n-k}$$

Comment: Why does the first equality hold?

Comment: It's the law of total probabilities

Comment: Ah ok! I see!! As for the expected value we have : \begin{equation*}E[Z_1]=E[XY_1] =E[X]\cdot E[Y_1]=p_0\cdot np=np_0p\end{equation*} right? As for the covariance we have : $$\text{Cov}(Z_1, Z_2)=E[Z_1Z_2]-E[Z_1]E[Z_2]=E[Z_1Z_2]-E[Z_1]^2$$ or not? But how is $E[Z_1Z_2]$ defined?